# How to solve error:Server Error in '/WebUI/Editors/2011Extensions' Application in Tridion?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, iis-6, tridion

I am trying to add a ribbon tool bar button in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 by using a custom editor configured in IIS. I need to open a pop-up aspx page when a user clicks on the ribbon toolbar button.

Clicking the button returns:

Server Error in '/WebUI/Editors/2011Extensions' Application.

> Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the
> processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
> Please review the specific error details below and modify your
> configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
> allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
> error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
> application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 14:  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 15: 
Line 16:    <membership>
Line 17:       <providers>
Line 18:          <clear />
```

`enter code here`Source File: D:\SampleProjects_Tridion\RTFExtensions\popups\web.config    Line: 16

Show Additional Configuration Errors:

> It is an error to use a section registered as
> allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
> error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
> application in IIS.
> (D:\SampleProjects_Tridion\RTFExtensions\popups\web.config line 23)
>
> It is an error to use a section registered as
> allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
> error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
> application in IIS.
> (D:\SampleProjects_Tridion\RTFExtensions\popups\web.config line 30)
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET >Version:4.0.30319.272

After this I also tried to change the virtual directory to application. Still I am getting the same error. Please Help in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a web.config in your pop-ups folder. This should not really be necessary. You only need one in the root folder of your editor.

You mention that this occurs when you click the button. Can we assume that the new ribbon item shows correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your response.It is showing correctly,but it is not displaying the icon image. What exactly you mean "Root folder"?

Comment: I imagine you have added a virtual folder to IIS and referenced it in the install path of the SDL Tridion System.Config file. That is the folder I am referring too.

In order for your button image to show up, you will need the correct CSS etc. Have you added that? This post may help with that

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466924/within-a-tridion-gui-extension-how-to-add-an-icon-to-the-context-menu

Comment: Even after removing the web.config from popups folder I am getting the following error: The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the <compilation> element of the Web.config file.

Comment: That seems quite self explanatory, and not an SDL Tridion related issue. Have you looked at your web.config file? Do you see <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" /> in there?